# Can I travel to Russia if I hold a Switzerland L permit?

Tags: russia, covid-19, switzerland

Knowing that you can travel to Russia if you are a "resident of Switzerland", is the [L permit](https://www.expatica.com/ch/moving/visas/switzerland-work-visa-102462/) enough to be considered resident?

It really is not obvious to understand what constitutes a residency, and maybe not all permits grant the same international status.

Comment: This question is about COVID and not about passport/visa, right?

Comment: **Who** allows you to *travel to Russia if you are a "resident of Switzerland"*. Is this a Russian visa application requirement?? Permit L – is a short-term residence permit that allows you to stay in Switzerland **for up to one year**.  The L permit is tied to the terms of the employment contract and may be extended **in exceptional cases for a further year** but no more if you continue to work for the same employer.

Comment: If this **only** about covid, then the goal is to determine where you have been in the last few months. Then you will probably be considered a resident, since you have been residing there durring the last few months.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Russia doesn't care where you've been. I'll say this **again**, different countries set different criteria. Some are about where you're a citizen, others where you're a resident, yet others where you've been within a certain timeframe. As for Russia, citizens and residents of Switzerland, who are arriving directly from Switzerland, can enter

Comment: @CGCampbell, let's say Germany, but this does not change anything.

Comment: @asiegf According to the embassy webpage yes. Writing an answer

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi, yes, it's more about COVID and the current times

Comment: @MarkJohnson, are you saying that they won't even care about the L permit?

Comment: @asiegf They do - COVID-19 or not, non-Swiss citizens have always needed to send in the residence permit (either in person at the embassy, or by post at an outsoured visa centre, the latter being more expensive)

Comment: @asiegf If they want only proof of residence, then they will probably accept the Permit B, C and L (described in the given link) as proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you need a Russian visa, this is in practice up to the Russian embassy. With a valid visa you're unlikely to be sent back.

Per the website of the Russian embassy in Berne ([LINK](https://switzerland.mid.ru/wiederaufnahme-der-visumausstellung)):

> ...nimmt die Konsularabteilung der Russischen Botschaft in der Schweiz die Ausstellung von Visa an ausländische Staatsbürger und Staatenlose mit ständigem Wohnsitz in der Schweiz wieder auf, welche  über das entsprechende Dokument der zuständigen Schweizer Behörden (Genehmigung der Kategorien B, C, L) verfügen.

As such, an L permit is enough.

Furthermore you'll need a negative PCR test issued max 72 hours before arrival, and must arrive on a direct flight from Switzerland.